# Spring Cloud DataFlow run Composed Task multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Is there any way to tell Composed task runner (CTR) to run composed task multiple times?

For now, in SCDF 1.2.3.RELEASE and CTR 1.0.0.RELEASE, if particular task in composed task has been completed, CTR doesn't execute it again.

Comment: Do you mean launching the composed task again? or, restarting the stopped/failed composed task. Did you see this doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks


  [1]:

Comment: I mean launching the same composed task again.

Answer (score 0):

A composed-task is a graph (represented in a DSL) defining a series of steps where each step can be a task or a batch-job. Once the composed-task is launched, it will execute all the steps and its transitions as defined by the DSL.

Unless you schedule the composed-task to launch on the desired frequency *(e.g., "every 1hr"; "every day at 11p" etc.)*, it won't automatically re-execute it. Please consider using a scheduler for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What I need is when some event raises - my code should launch the same composed task again. 
Probably, I would launch it with different args, but for now it seems `--composed-task-arguments` doesn't work, so I have to use DB to share data between tasks in composed task.